# Unable to parse Sendgrid parse api raw callback into Griddler email object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, griddler

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Have all emails send to my domain parsed for the content of their to, body, subject line and ... in order for me to construct a fax object from it and send it as a fax

So far I have been able to setup my MX record to point to Sendgrid and from Sendgrid's Parse API using Ngrok I get the callback in my localhost server. The next step is to get the raw object into an object I could work with. This lead me to Thoughbot's [Griddler Gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler).

This is how I have setup my app so far:

Sendgrid Setup:
URL: https://8c00fab0.ngrok.io/email_processor | Spam Check and Send Raw are both checked

As mentioned before this part works since I do receive this:

```
Parameters: {"dkim"=>"{@gmail.com : pass}", "email"=>"Received: by mx0034p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id 253FfvZ40f Wed, 09 Sep 2015 22:31:48 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: from mail-qg0-f54.google.com (mail-qg0-f54.google.com [209.85.192.54]) by mx0034p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 63848A83017 for <14085552422@faxbyemail.co>; Wed,  9 Sep 2015 22:31:48 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: by qgx61 with SMTP id 61so21251135qgx.3 for <14085552422@faxbyemail.co>; Wed, 09 Sep 2015 15:31:48 -0700 (PDT)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:content-type; bh=Wo6p7CSlR30aGxf5SwjuZ2klt31URDqTZUHrKdmLz7s=; b=fWfFOQ4YOtijYvphYL9/1shyzK8CBTcHS37s89t9Qn4xK8OrXwVKtmGtNnwg7a1n48 JHkEeAdxVvRMpinxPllGiJoPNy0ivVN36uEYbsrLTcZVlx9RIIl8u5PjmrE1aqlnkjPy gOcbfJunVCFZLaLpv3RB/GiNYL1bodgW7nn8sMTmwN5EwoH7SncS7cle4ksPadgiGv9f DVoJniX2yuMqygSVLT4Qrk4JDzR6G2oj1Fz3QkcrQfNKxOS6iyBhpnh3cDuUi8GTSVYl Nqq2dtKlUNqI+U9ojtG1BjGVUKbP0v5apF3Wvmj72p8L0AB3FHqL8uvFnhi2dGTFVq+y 6nUQ==\nX-Received: by 10.140.233.137 with SMTP id e131mr48879201qhc.37.1441837907953; Wed, 09 Sep 2015 15:31:47 -0700 (PDT)\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nFrom: Sam Sedighian <samansb@gmail.com>\nDate: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 22:31:38 +0000\nMessage-ID: <CAEMkzYbhsLLB3NPLznG+-RibP5kzDG5yTT++mQL1ep-vH6_orA@mail.gmail.com>\nSubject: test 20\nTo: \"14085552422@faxbyemail.co\" <14085552422@faxbyemail.co>\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11354d8053d2d1051f580c22\n\n--001a11354d8053d2d1051f580c22\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\nbody etxt\n\n--001a11354d8053d2d1051f580c22\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n<div dir=\"ltr\">body etxt</div>\n\n--001a11354d8053d2d1051f580c22--\n", "to"=>"\"14085552422@faxbyemail.co\" <14085552422@faxbyemail.co>", "from"=>"Sam Sedighian <samansb@gmail.com>", "sender_ip"=>"209.85.192.54", "spam_report"=>"Spam detection software, running on the system \"mx0034p1mdw1.sendgrid.net\", has\nidentified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original message\nhas been attached to this so you can view it (if it isn't spam) or label\nsimilar future email.  If you have any questions, see\n@@CONTACT_ADDRESS@@ for details.\n\nContent preview:  body etxt body etxt [...] \n\nContent analysis details:   (0.0 points, 5.0 required)\n\n pts rule name              description\n---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------\n 0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is freemail (samansb[at]gmail.com)\n 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message\n 0.0 T_MIME_NO_TEXT         No text body parts\n\n", "envelope"=>"{\"to\":[\"14085552422@faxbyemail.co\"],\"from\":\"samansb@gmail.com\"}", "subject"=>"test 20", "spam_score"=>"0.012", "charsets"=>"{\"to\":\"UTF-8\",\"subject\":\"UTF-8\",\"from\":\"UTF-8\"}", "SPF"=>"pass"}
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'griddler'
gem 'griddler-sendgrid'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
griddler (1.2.1)
  htmlentities
  rails (>= 3.2.0)
griddler-sendgrid (0.0.1)
  griddler
```

**routes.rb**

```
post '/email_processor' => 'fax#sendgrid'
# this corresponds to the following route when I rake route:
# email_processor POST   /email_processor(.:format) fax#sendgrid
```

**config/initializers/griddler.rb**

```
Griddler.configure do |config|
  config.processor_class = EmailProcessor
  config.processor_method = :process
  config.reply_delimiter = '-- REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE --'
  config.email_service = :sendgrid
end
```

**app/controllers/fax_controller.rb**

```
def sendgrid
  EmailProcessor.new(params).process
end
```

**app/models/email_processor.rb**

```
class EmailProcessor

  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
    @from = email.from
    @body = email.body
  end

  def self.process(email)
    Fax.create({params go here})
  end

end
```

I end up giving a Completed 500 Internal server error - Since I do not pass a 200 OK back to Sendgrid but the important part is that I get the following error in my log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `from' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fc742a33070>):
  app/models/email_processor.rb:5:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/fax_controller.rb:31:in `new'
  app/controllers/fax_controller.rb:31:in `sendgrid'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're bypassing the work Griddler does on the controller side. You're pointing Sendgrid at a controller and action you created yourself. Instead I think you want to point to Griddler's controller and action. See [the README under "Installation"](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler#installation).

Change your `routes.rb` to be:

```
# your own route
# post '/email_processor' => 'fax#sendgrid'

# griddler's
post '/email_processor' => 'griddler/emails#create'
```

If you [take a look at Griddler's controller](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler/blob/master/app/controllers/griddler/emails_controller.rb) you'll see that there are a few things it does for you to get things into your email processor class.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this in Rails is to gather the email params in the Controller.

For instance, in a sample app I created, people email selfies to our Parse API.  In my selfie_controller.rb, I have a route '/inbound' and I have the following:

```
def inbound

    if !params['attachment1'].nil? and params['attachment1'].content_type == "image/jpeg"

        Selfy.create!({ pic: params['attachment1'], email: params['from'] })

    end

end
```

The call to Selfy.create! uses the selfy.rb model, but I gather the params from the email to send to that from the controller.

Is this something you could try?

Comment: Apologies, just realised - this ISN'T using Griddler, just doing things manually.  (Griddler is a little unnecessary for this)

Comment: From the looks of it I might just have to do this manually. I was trying to avoid it since I did not wanted to deal with corner cases. However, your answer is definitely useful for going manual. thanks